# Session isset but not save after close and open browser

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I have some code in php and i want to save session cookies after close and open browser. Session is not saving after closing browser. Well, how can i solve it

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
        $password = $_POST['passwd'];
        $email = $_POST['mail'];
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND passwd = '$password'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($row) {
            if (!empty($_POST['remember'])) {
                $result = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE email = '$email' ";
                setcookie("logged_in", $email, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = $row['username'];
                header("Location: index.php");
            }else {
                if (isset($_COOKIE['logged_in'])) {
                    setcookie('logged_in', '');
                }
                header("Location: index.php");
            }
        } else {
            #echo('<script> alert("sdada")</script>');
            header("location:registration.php");
        }
    }
```

My index.php page

```
  <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
                 echo "<li><a href='page5.php'><i class='fa fa-user'></i>  ".$_SESSION['logged_in']."</a> </li>";
                 echo "<li> <a href='logout.php'><i class='fa fa-sign-in'></i> Logout</a> </li>";
            }else{
                    echo "<li><a href='registration.php'><i class='fa fa-user'></i> Sign Up</a> </li>";
                    echo "<li> <a href='signin.php'><i class='fa fa-sign-in'></i> Login</a> </li>";
                 }
        ?>
```

Comment: is your browser clears cookies and browse data on exit?

Comment: I'm not sure the exact flow but can you check by comment this condition `if (isset($_COOKIE['logged_in'])) {
                    // setcookie('logged_in', '');`